How to update getManifests function
I hope all are doing well.
I have query regarding Manifest.js file which generates at runtime or after bundle or update everytime we update any component in spfx.
There is a function called "getManifests". Anyone know how and from where can I update it. So that every time it updates manifest.js file the logic which I want mention it should update the same there. Also please let me know the possibility of the same
I tried updating it by myself in manifest.js directly but on every change it updates automatically
